# How can I rewrite the url using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I tried to rewrite my url from i.e. "www.example.com/article.php?title=blub" to "www.example.com/blub"

But it doesn't work.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*)\.html$ article.php?title=$1
```

This code works, but only with an html extension.

But, I don't want to use this extension.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wiki/

# we don't want to rewrite existent directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# we don't want to rewrite existent files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ article.php?title=$1 [L]
```

The problem with your code is that it doesn't check if a file exists so when you redirect it without the `\.html` it enters a loop as it doesn't care if `article.php` exists or not.

As talked thru the comments the OP found that his file was not on the root folder as he described on his question `www.example.com/article.php?title=blub` but rather on a sub folder called `wiki`.

Comment: Thank you, it has helped me a little bit, but there's still a problem:
It rewrites all non existent pages. And another problem: The new URL is breaking at the question mark, so

"www.example.com/blub"

redirects to 

"www.example.com/article.php"

Comment: **It's also worth pointing that if you have other rules on your `.htaccess` you should tell me as they can affect the outcome of the above.** That being said, if you don't have any other rules. Rename your `article.php` to `articles.backup.php` and create a new `article.php` file with the content `<?php print_r($_GET); ?>` to make sure it really isn't passing down any arguments to it as it should, so I can only think your article file does not know what to do with the arguments its been given.

Comment: Also keep in mind that the above `.htaccess` rule is to make `www.example.com/blub` work, so if you access `www.example.com/blub` it should internally show you the content of `www.example.com/article.php?title=blub` without changing the browser URL.

Comment: No, the php file is correct.

The Error:

"Not Found

The requested URL /article.php was not found on this server."

Comment: That error means you have no `article.php` at `domain.com/article.php`, so where is the file at?

Comment: Yes, that's very strange, because the file is existing:
http://img5.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/hjhjg1vxy8czp2.png

Comment: I've tested it, the .htaccess searches the file in the main folder of the domain and not in the folder with the .htaccess file.

Comment: I changed it into 
`RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ wiki/article.php?title=$1 [L]`
So it works, but non existing pages will rewrited too.
The last problem is to only rewrite url's without an extension.

Comment: That's because you only copied the rule and not what I had pointed out on my answer along with it. They even have comments explaining what they do.

Comment: yes, and because of this, I viewed right now on this comments and with a little bit of using google I got the solution. ^^

For all people, who have the same problem:

`Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ wiki/article.php?title=$1 [L]`

Thank you for your help.

Comment: the file was on the same folder, but the .htaccess searched it one directory before.

I will do it tomorrow, thank you for the hint.

Comment: @Reese If the `.htaccess` was inside the `wiki` folder along with the `article.php` file then all you have to do is change `RewriteBase /` to `RewriteBase /wiki/` instead of changing the `RewriteRule`. And next time don't forget to provide that information on your question so that people know your situation.